# Why is ExecuteSQLRecord taking a long time to start outputting flow files on large tables?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using the ExecuteSQLRecord processor to dump the contents of a large table (100 GB) with 100+ million records.

I have set up the properties like below. However, what I am noticing is that it takes a good 45 minutes before I see any flow files coming out of this processor?

What am I missing?

[image: properties of ExecuteSQLRecord]

I am on NiFi 1.9.1

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to try GenerateTableFetch -> ExecuteSQLRecord, this way the first processor calculates the "fetch queries", and then ExecuteSQLRecord will work on the smaller fetch queries.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I will give it a try,

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to ExecuteSQL(Record) or even GenerateTableFetch -> ExecuteSQL(Record) is to use QueryDatabaseTable without a Max-Value Column. It has a Fetch Size property that attempts to set the number of rows returned on each pull from the database. Oracle's [default is 10](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#i1023619) for example, so with 10000 rows per flow file, ExecuteSQL has to make 1000 trips to the DB, fetching 10 rows at a time. I recommend setting Fetch Size to Max Rows Per Flow File as a general rule, then one fetch is made per outgoing flow file.

The Fetch Size property should be available to the ExecuteSQL processors as well, I wrote up Apache Jira [NIFI-6865](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6865) to cover this improvement.

Comment: one of my requirements is to have the output as JSON. So need to use the QueryDatabaseTableRecord processor. However, still seeing the initial delay with that. I set the Fetch Size to Max Rows Per Flow File both to 10000. I set the Output Batch Size to 1, so it can emit a flowfile as soon as one is ready.